# PHP Email piping, local delivery error

Tags: php, email, pipe

The problem is that I get the "local delivery failed" email back to the address I am sending email to. I have a forward set to an email with a link to .php file like this:

```
"|/home/admin/domains/test.dev/public_html/pipe.php"
```

Now the file itself has this following code:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/php -q
<?php

$to      = 'test@test.dev';
$subject = 'test';
$headers = 'From: test@localhost.dev' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, 'test pipe', $headers);
```

What should I fix? Path to the file seems good and it has 777 permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrong php library folder. Contacted my hosting provider and changed the link to:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php53
```

now it's working.